# 3x3 array = 10 numbers

Tags: c, arrays

i have this code

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int n = 3;
const int s = 3;
int getm(int mat[n][s]);
int printm(int mat[n][s]);

int main()
{
    int m[n][s];
    getm(m);
    printm(m);
    return 0;
}

int getm(int mat[n][s])
{
    for(int x = 0;x < n;x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0;y<s;y++)
        {
            scanf("%i ", &mat[x][y]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int printm(int mat[n][s])
{
    for(int x = 0;x<n;x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0;y<s;y++)
        {
            printf("%i ", mat[x][y]);
            if(y==(s-1))
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which shoud ask for 9 numbers to make a 3x3 matrix array, but it actually asks for 10 numbers, printm is working well - printing only 9 numbers. Where is error?

Comment: Try to trace `x` and `y` values in the double for-loop in `getm`, via printf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scanf("%i ", &mat[x][y]);
```

Get rid of the space after `%i`, so it only reads a number:

```
scanf("%i", &mat[x][y]);
```

Answer (score 7):

I think the problem is the space after `%i`: you do not need the tenth number, but your code is asking for it anyway, because it waits to get a space after the ninth number.

Separately, your printing code can be optimized a little by dropping the `if`:

```
for(int x = 0;x<n;x++)
{
    for(int y = 0;y<s;y++)
    {
        printf("%i ", mat[x][y]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: It's waiting for a _non-space_ after scanning the ninth, the `"%i "` format eats all whitespace after the number including newlines.

Comment: An interesting exercise: Make a file, called nums, say, containing only `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` with no space after the 9.  Running `cat nums | ./a.out` will work; it does not wait for the space.  When running `./a.out` only, using the console for standard input, a single space after the last number does not help.  You can enter zillions of spaces but nothing prints until some non-blank entry is made.

Comment: @RayToal I expect you know it, but still: `cat` closes the stream when reaching the end of file, so `scanf` gets the message. With console input, while the stream is not closed, `scanf` waits for more whitespace. Ctrl-D (or on Windows Ctrl-Z, iirc) would also get the message across.

Comment: Yep, +1.  Even though the OP was asking only about the console behavior of scanf, it's fun to generalize. :)